# How to specify which jar signer to use in Ivy

Tags: java, ant, ivy

I can't figure out how to tell the resolver to use x jar signer. I've defined it in the ivysettings like so:

```
<signers>
    <pgp name="pkcs12" password="xxxxxx" secring="${dir.fglweb}/keystore"/>
</signers>

<resolvers >
    <chain name="libraries" returnFirst="true" >
        <ibiblio name="maven" m2compatible="true"/>
        <filesystem name="local" >
            <artifact pattern="${basedir}/tools/ivy/repository/[artifact].[ext]"/>
        </filesystem>

    </chain>
</resolvers>
```

But I'm not sure to to actually tell my settings to use the signer.

[Documentation](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.2.0/settings/resolvers.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation suggests using the "signer" attribute as follows:

```
<filesystem name="local" signer="pkcs12">
    <artifact pattern="${basedir}/tools/ivy/repository/[artifact].[ext]"/>
</filesystem>
```

---

Notes:

- Your artifact pattern does not include a "revision" is that deliberate?

Comment: Yes, the not included revision is deliberate. I tried the extra attribute you added, I tried using jarsigner -verify "jar.jar" to check if it got signed, and it didnt appear to work